# Debugger output not shown

Tags: python, ipython, pytest

I am running into a problem while running `ipdb` within a test containing [the `capfd` fixture](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html).  A cut down version of the test code is as thus:

```
import pytest
import sys

def test_foo(capfd):
    def foo():
        print("Hello World!")
    foo()
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    import ipdb
    ipdb.set_trace()
    assert out == "Hello World!\n"
```

When I run `py.test -s test/test_capfb.py`, all the output of the debugger is captured and I see nothing.  I can still issue commands (for example the `c` in the output below) to the debugger but get no output until the whole process finishes its run.  A sample of the output is here:

```
; py.test -s tests/test_capfb.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/usr/repos/junk, inifile: setup.cfg
plugins: bdd-2.16.0, colordots-0.1, cov-2.2.1, html-1.7, pep8-1.0.6, xdist-1.14, catchlog-1.2.2
collected 1 items
tests/test_capfb.py 
c  <---- I typed this!
--Return--
None
> /home/usr/repos/junk/tests/test_capfb.py(12)test_foo()
     11     import ipdb
---> 12     ipdb.set_trace()
     13
ipdb> .
========================== 1 passed in 228.90 seconds ==========================
```

Is there any way to tell `pytest` to stop capturing stdout/stderr when `ipdb` is involved?

Comment: For now, if possible, run your tests with nosetests - ipdb detects that nose is loaded and stops it capturing stdout. It looks like there's going to be a more general way to do it in the next version (0.9.1): https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/pull/84/files

Comment: @ThomasK: Your work around does not work since `nose` knows nothing of [py.test fixtures](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html). Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I can use [iocapture](https://github.com/oinume/iocapture) to capture the output like thus:

```
import pytest
import sys
import iocapture

def test_foo():
    def foo():
        print("Hello World!")
    out = None
    with iocapture.capture() as captured:
        foo()
        out = captured.stdout
    import ipdb
    ipdb.set_trace()
    assert out == "Hello World!\n"
```